# Complicated Javascript Reg Exp

Tags: javascript, regex

I've searched the previous questions about Reg Exp's but didn't find the help I need. I am rather a beginner in regular expressions and need a Javascript reg exp that limits a valid *filename* to the following:

- Allow only `A-Za-z0-9_-.` (*alphanumeric*, *underscore*, *hyphen*, *dot*)
- However, *filename* **cannot start** with a *hyphen* or *dot*
- *Filename* **cannot end** with a *dot*
- Only **single** *dot*s in *filename*, no `..`
- **No** *space*s
- Maximum length: **255**

I appreciate any assistance with this. Also, any thoughts about proper filenames is welcome. I believe the aforementioned requirements will serve me, but I can always hear more thoughts on the subject. I am creating a web-based application where people can upload documents. I'd prefer to just create universal filename limits and not be concerned with OS type. Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to add that while it cannot begin with a . or -, it must also only start with the valid chars: A-Za-z0-9_

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are you doing on the server side to protect against people who don't enable Javascript?

Comment: Why a regexp ? You can simply test several rule to trigger a clear error message. For example, start and end is quite easy to test. No spaces is redundant with only A-Za-z0-9_-.

Comment: Does it really need to be a single regex? Overlapping requirements like this can be *much* more readable as multiple regexes (*e.g.* `if (str.match(/^[a-z0-9_\-\.]+$/i) && ! str.match(/^\./) && ...)`)

Comment: Ah, many replies just as I posted my reply. Thanks, I'll try the multiple expressions path. Thanks for your reply. I have tried many variations of literal expressions and lookaheads/behinds.... I use sites that allow testing of regex but to no avail. Not sure how to create what I need, so thought i'd ask for some guidance.  As for why I would like JavaScript, once I get that, then I will be able to figure out the PHP side of it. Although, you're right, should mention I'll need the server side version just in case it has to be rather different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Allow only A-Za-z0-9_-. (alphanumeric, underscore, hyphen, dot)

That can be handled with

```
result = /^[\w.-]+$/.test(input);
```

> However, filename cannot start with a hyphen or dot

That can be handled with

```
result = !/^[-.]/.test(input);
```

> Filename cannot end with a dot

That can be handled with

```
result = !/\.$/.test(input);
```

> Only single dots in filename, no `..`

That can be handled with

```
result = !/\.\./.test(input);
```

> No spaces

That's already handled by the first point

> Maximum length: 255

That can be handled with

```
result = input.length < 256;
```

---

All together you've got:

```
function validate(input) {
    return /^[\w.-]+$/.test(input) &&
        !/^[-.]/.test(input) &&
        !/\.$/.test(input) &&
        !/\.\./.test(input) &&
        input.length < 256;
}
```

Which is simple, easy enough to read and easier to debug.

Comment: Tried answer from @aaron_world_traveler with the .* removed: `^(?!.*\.\.)\w[\w.-]{0,253}[\w-]$|^\w$` This works fine, and the answer from @zzzzBov also works great. They and @RichardHamilton took time to explain each line and I got to sit at the foot of the masters and get some learnin'. I do like the idea of making my code easier to debug - what if my requirement for filenames has to change in the future? With multiple, smaller expressions, a beginner like me can more easily examine them and figure things out. I learned from all 3 and if I could choose all as answers i would.

Comment: Plus, I did console.log() for each line so I could examine which expressions where catching what.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!.*\..*\.)\w[\w.-]{0,253}[\w-]$|^\w$
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/jI0lP0/1)

Explanation:

- `^` - starting from the beginning of the string
- `(?!.*\..*\.)` - a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ensure there are no two dots
- `\w` - equivalent to one `A-Za-z0-9_` character
- `[\w.-]{0,253}` - upto 253 of all of the listed possible characters
- `[\w-]` - all possible characters, except for dot
- `$` - the end of the string
- `|^\w$` - all that or a single `A-Za-z0-9_` character

Comment: A couple problems here, this won't match single character filenames, and also I believe the intention was to not allow filenames with two consecutive dots, i.e. `^(?!.*\.\.)\w[\w.-]{0,253}[\w-]$`

Comment: @aaron_world_traveler, my understanding was that there shouldn't be more than one dot at all, not just consecutive. If that is the case, it can easily be fixed my removing the `.*` as you showed. Good point about the single character filename. Fixed.

Comment: i'd imagine if he's trying to match valid filenames, then two non consecutive dots are fine, as that is a valid filename pattern on most OSes.  Plus, his text specifically states `no ..`

Comment: I don't see anywhere for me to select one answer over another. I need to head out and will finish testing out your awesome answers when I return. I will post what worked for me later. Thanks!!

Comment: @aaron_world_traveler, it's not entirely clear if the `..` is just an example. In the comments OP stated *never more than one dot*.

Comment: @Darren - you mean never more than one consecutive dot, correct?  `blah.blah.txt` is ok but `blah..txt` is not, correct?  At least, that matches the usual valid filename patterns for most OSes...

Comment: @aaron_world_traveler, in unix systems there is no problem to have files named `foo..bar` for example. Not sure, but my guess will be that it's not a problem in windows either. So probably OP's restriction was more of the idea *after the dot there is a file extension and no more dots*.

Comment: @ndn Yep, that certainly could be what he meant.  @Darren?  Either way, you've got the solution here on the page in mine or ndn's answer.

Comment: It seems each OS has its own valid filename requirements, with modern systems not something to worry about too much. With each difference I found I chose to make it a limitation. For example, one OS didn't like hyphens as the first character, so I just made that a restriction. I know two dots can be valid, yet if the answer is consecutive dots are allowed on SOME systems, then again, I added it as a limitation. I want to keep things simple and my users won't be concerned with whether they can use two dots or not, so out it goes. I'm currently checking out the awesome answers given.

Answer (score 0):

This regex gets really close. The only problem is that it doesn't match two or more consecutive dots.

```
var fileRegex = /^[\w][\w-\.]{0,253}[\w-]$/
```

Breakdown

`/^[\w]` - It can only start with a word character and can't start with a dot or hyphen

`[\w-\.]` - Can contain a word character, hyphen or dot

`{0,253}` - Matches between 0 and 253 of the previous expression

`[\w-]$` - Can end with a word character or hyphen only.

Here is the regex for matching consecutive dots

```
var dotRegex = /(\.)\1+/
```

OR

```
var dotRegex = /\.{2,}/
```

To see if a string matches a regular expression, we can use the `test` method. We want the first regex to pass and the second regex to fail.

`fileRegex.test(string) && !dotRegex.test(string)`

Comment: This doesn't exclude multiple dots.

Comment: The way I understand the question the filename shouldn't contain more than one dot at all, not just consecutive. Even then, why use back references and not just `/\.\.+/` or `/\.{2,}/`?

Comment: why not just `/\.\./` ?  As long as two consecutive dots are found, it's invalid, regardless of how many more dots are consecutively found.

Comment: I believe my intention was that a valid filename could have single dots between valid characters, not at the start or end, and never more than one dot. thanks

Comment: shoot, I meant never more than one dot between valid characters. so no consecutive dots. Hope that clarified things.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do it with a single regex:

```
^(?!.*\.\.)(?=\w)[\w.-]{0,254}[\w-]$
```

Comment: @ndn - ah yes...sorry, I was in PCRE-mode.  Answer edited.